# IE11 vertical scroll freeze when scrollleft is non-zero

Tags: html, internet-explorer

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lxgd3km/2/

Run the above fiddle in IE11/edge. Basically you can't scroll.

If you change the css line to remove `overflow-x: hidden`, then it scrolls with a horizontal scrollbar.

Can I make the scroll work without having the horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it using transform instead of setting scrollleft.

```
  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  // container.scrollLeft = 20;
  container.querySelector('table').style.transform = 'translateX(-20px)';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lxgd3km/3/

Apparently, IE to have better support for css transform than scrolls.